# Discord.py cannot get user from payload in on_raw_reaction_add event

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to write a bot which can give roles if a user is reacting to the specific message. But my problem is that the member variable is NONE. Can anyone help me?

```
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    if payload.message_id == client.data.get("rulemessage"):
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g: g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)
        if payload.emoji.name == "✅":
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Accepted Rules")
            member = discord.utils.get(guild.members, id=payload.user_id)
            await member.add_roles(role)
```

And this is the Error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PROJECT_ROOT\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "PROJECT_ROOT/main.py", line 57, in on_raw_reaction_add
    await member.add_roles(role)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_roles'
```

Comment: Have you enabled intents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the on_raw_reaction_add event, you can just use `payload.member` to get the member. Also make sure to enable intents.

```
if payload.emoji.name == "✅":
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Accepted Rules")
    await payload.member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: Thanks that works! Is it a new feature or why I didn´t see it in any tutorials?

Comment: Yes, it has been added in discord.py 1.3 and also keep in mind that this will not work on the `on_raw_reaction_remove` event. In there you will have to first get the guild with `payload.guild_id` & then get the guild member with the `payload.user_id`.